Fill a listbox in a form from a list of data in a worksheet
I'm currently trying to fill a listbox in a form from data listed in a worksheets (i use a hidden worksheet as a sort of .ini).
Here is my attempt, i initialize my range which is dynamic (or sort of)
Private Sub Connect_frm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Product_Range As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim List_Size As Integer

Set ws_datas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datas")

'fillproduct list
i = 2
Do While ws_datas.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
i = i + 1
Loop
List_Size = i - 1

'define the size of the range of data for the listbox
Set Product_Range = ws_datas.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(List_Size, 1))

'define source data for the listbox
Product_Range_ListBox.ColumnCount = 1
Product_Range_ListBox.Clear
Product_Range_ListBox.RowSource = Product_Range

End Sub

the thing is that my box stays empty
Edit, i've currently modified the code at the beginning to be more efficient :
    Private Sub Connect_frm_Initialize()
    Dim ws_Data As Worksheet
    Dim List_Size As Long
    Set ws_Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    
    'Get the size of the list **More efficient mode**
    List_Size = ws_Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'display for debug
    ws_Data.Range("D2").Value = List_Size
    
    Me.Product_Range_ListBox.RowSource = "Data!A2:A" & List_Size
    
    End Sub

I've tried also adding more explicitly the range as input of the rowsource but nope, do not work.
The debug written in D2 seems to work if I create a sub somewhere else but not in initialize....
@black cat, I will look into the .parent.name thing, I do not exactly understand what that means. Thanks for your help.

Pls try Product_Range_ListBox.RowSource = Product_Range.Address

Hello, You're right for the .Address at the end on the line but do not seem to work though.
I do have data in the sheet, so I do not understand...
Thanks for your help

I found my answer, the main issue is that i did not named correctly the initialization :
Private Sub Connect_frm_Initialize()
to
Private Sub User_Form_Initialize()
And now it works, i'm just SOOOOOOOO Noob
